# Input file name as command

Tags: c++

I have to program to read some values from a Input text file.

```
int main(){

    FILE *pf;
    int i;
    int j;   

    pf = fopen("input.txt" , "r");

    fscanf(pf ,"%d , %d" , &i ,&j );

    printf("%d ,%d\n" , i ,j);

    fclose(pf);
}
```

and Input.txt has some values.
Can anyone suggest me a way to get input.txt after running the program.

For example :

```
Open a terminal 
compile the code
Run the code
---Here it should ask for the file name---
```

Comment: you tagged this with C++, but your code looks like pure C. Are you using C or C++?

Comment: @DougT. He apparently just uses C library. If it is pure C it won't compile because he does not have a return statement for main function.

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```
    #include <fstream>
    #include <iostream>

    int main()
    {
       std::string filename;
       cin >> filename;
       ifstream inFile;
       inFile.open(filename.append(".txt");
       int a;
       while (inFile)
       {
          inFile >> a;
          cout << a;
       }
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way to only get the file name from user and append .txt at pf = fopen(filename, "r"); ?

Answer (score 1):

Command line arguments:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::cout << argv[1] << '\n';
}
```

Or stdin:

```
int main() {
  std::string filename;
  std::cout << "enter file name: ";
  std::cin >> filename;
  std::cout << filename << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I edited the program like this:  std::string filename;
  std::cout << "enter file name: ";
  std::cin >> filename;
  std::cout << filename << '\n';

pf = fopen(filename, "r");

Comment: I edited my code like below

    std::string filename;
    std::cout << "enter file name: ";
    std::cin >> filename;
    std::cout << filename << '\n';
    pf = fopen(filename, "r");

But i am getting an error :readfile.cpp:19:25: error: cannot convert ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘FILE* fopen(const char*, const char*)’

Comment: Is there a way to only get the file name from user and append .txt at  pf = fopen(filename, "r"); ?

Comment: @Rdvsm Yeah, you can say `fopen((filename + ".txt").c_str(), "r");` or `filename += ".txt"; fopen(filename.c_str(), "r");`